# Learning how to do quicksort

Tags: algorithm, sorting

I am in university trying to learn how to use quick sort. I am going to make a program in a couple weeks on it, but first I am trying to understand how it works. I found a homework problem that looks like it will help me understand. The only problem is, after looking at Wikipedia and a couple other sites I am just left confused and hopeless.

Apply quicksort to the sequence A = { 6, 4, 3, 9, 4, 7, 5 }. Instead of the median‐of‐three based pivot, use 
the first subsequence element. (This introduces the risk of worst case performance but it makes the 
problem easier to solve by hand.) 
Show your work as follows. Indicate when an element becomes a pivot by putting a square around it. 
Later, indicate that an element is/was a pivot by underlining it. Use dot markers and arrows to indicate 
how the left‐right search for which elements to swap progresses. Do the work as the recursion dictates: 
that is, process left subsequences before right subsequences.  
That is,

6  4  3  9  4  7  5    identify pivot

5  4  3  9  4  7  6   move pivot out of the way and search for elements to swap

Can someone explain to me step by step how this works?

Comment: There are many partitioning algorithms (algorithms for rearranging the sequence around the pivot) available. Can you describe which one you're supposed to use?

Comment: [does this link help you?](http://www.sorting-algorithms.com/quick-sort), explanation of the workings, plus a visualization of what it does under different circumstances.

Comment: i think wikipedia explains it pretty well... http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort

Answer (score 0):

A simple quicksort function is like:

1. Partition based on pivot - what this pivot function does is that it moves the pivot element on to its correct position (as it would be in sorted array).
   By correct position i mean, all elements on left of pivot will be less than the pivot element and on the right will be elements greater tan pivot.
2. quicksort () elements from  0 to new_index of pivot // this will sort elements on left using the partition approach recursively
3. quicksort() elements from new_indexof pivot +1 to last index // this way you will sort elements on right...

E.g.:

```
2 1 4 3 // first element as pivot,pivot =2
```

1. after partition

   1 2 4 3
2. quicksort(1)

   2.1 - uses partition finds one elements which means its sorted
   array to left =(1)
3. quicksort(4,3)

   3.1 partition 4,3
      array to right (3,4)